# how to handle and set the error, return and return value in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, error-handling, return, return-value

I am new in programming, can someone tell me what is the difference and how to handle the errors in python ?

```
def compare_files(file1, file2):
    status = 0
    try:
        with open(file1, 'rb') as f_file1, open(file2, 'rb') as f_file2:
            if f_file1.read() == f_file2.read():
                print 'SUCCESS \n'
            else:
                print 'FAILURE \n'
                status = 1
    except IOError:
        print "[Error]File is NOT compared"
        status = -1
    return status
```

is it possible to use return 1, return -1 or return 0 in the above program ? instead of using status = 0 , 1 and so on. I want to handle the errors in my program in an efficient way. so can someone explain or tell me how to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you can just use return  instead of assigning status to variable

```
def compare_files(file1, file2):
    try:
        with open(file1, 'rb') as f_file1, open(file2, 'rb') as f_file2:
            if f_file1.read() == f_file2.read():
                print 'SUCCESS \n'
                return 0
            else:
                print 'FAILURE \n'
                return 1
    except IOError:
        print "[Error]File is NOT compared"
        return -1
```

You probably want to handle it like this:

```
val = compare_files(file1, file2)
if val == 0:
    print "Files are the same"
elif var == 1:
    print "Files differ"
elif var == -1:
    print "Error"
```

But that doesn't give you any informations about what error cause status = -1

Comment: how to handle the return value in calling a function ?

Comment: Answer updated, maybe that is what you want to achieve